# Virtualbox doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, sound, virtualbox, shared-folders, guest-additions

I can't see shared folder and hear sound from VirtualBox. Guest Addtition installed without any problems, but still doesn't work. No such problem on upper versions of Ubuntu, but I need this one.

Comment: Virtualbox version? Have you try reinstall it?

Comment: You need to also install the Extension Pack in the host. That's likely what's missing now and wasn't before when you tried in the newer Ubuntu releases. This is more relevant than the VirtualBox version?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia no, extension pack necessary if somebody want VBox to have access to usb ports, I didn't use that for having shared folder.

Comment: @Jim tried VBox from repos (there two versions available: 5.0.3 and something else), also tried 6.0 from official site.